# JS change maker

Tags: javascript, html

I have been tasked with scripting a change maker in JavaScript and even after looking at similar situations (Beginner JS exercise: Change Maker) here I can not get this thing to work. Even literally correcting what was suggested in the other post and still nothing. Its's due soon and im losing my mind with this thing. Help!

I have updated to my current JS code

HTML

```
<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Change Calculator</h1>
        <label>Enter amount of change due (0-99):</label>
        <input type="text" id="cents" />
        <input type="button" value="Calculate" name="calculate" id="calculate" /><br><br>

        <label>Quarters:</label>
        <input type="text" id="quarters" disabled><br>

        <label>Dimes:</label>
        <input type="text" id="dimes" disabled><br>

        <label>Nickels:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nickels" disabled><br>
        
        <label>Pennies:</label>
        <input type="text" id="pennies" disabled><br>
      </main>
</body>
```

JavScript

```
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};
var makeChange = function(cents) {
    var quarters = parseInt(cents / 25); 
    var dimes = parseInt(((cents - (quarters * 25)) / 10)); 
    var nickels = parseInt(((cents - (quarters * 25)) - (dimes * 10)) / 5); 
    var pennies = parseInt(((cents - (quarters * 25)) - (dimes * 10))- (nickels * 5));
    return cents;
};
var processEntry = function() {
  var cents = parseInt($("cents").value);
  if (!isNaN(cents) || cents < 100 || cents > 0) {
    $("quarters").value = quarters;
    $("dimes").value = dimes;
    $("nickels").value = nickels;
    $("pennies").value = pennies;
  } else {
    alert("Please enter a number between 0-99")
};
window.onload = function() {
  $("calculate").onclick = processEntry;
  $("cents").focus();
}; };
```

Comment: So describe your problem. What is not working? What results you want to get? Also it's misleading to use `$` as variable. Common case is that `$` refers to jQuery, and you are not using it

Comment: The button does not work. There is no return or action that occurs. I need it to return the change broken down by coin. Sorry I should have explained. I just know this is a common exercise in computer science classes. Im using visual code studio and it is not displaying any errors.

Comment: -Justinas The $ as a variable has been used before without issue in another posting here titled (beginner JS exercise: change maker) the teacher included this as the only line written for the student in the JS file. The remaining $ are used in the attachment of eventhandlers to events as described in chapter 4 of my book

Comment: `cents` is used but never declared. You probably wanted `var cents` and not `var entry`. Also `makeChange` is declared in an inner scope but used elsewhere. And I'm sure there are errors, you are probably just not looking in the right place. Open your browser devtools (F12), check the errors in the console and use the sources tab to debug your code and step through it to see what it's doing and why. Also please indent and format your code properly, this would make it so much easier to see where scope blocks start and end!

Comment: -CherryDT thank you I have revised my JS hopefully it looks better and makes more sense. The Dev Tools you mentioned helped also. I got used to using PyCharm which allows me to run and see what the issue was in the IDE and havent completely gotten used to this new program yet. Currently my code shows no issues in the Dev tools anywhere I can find but the button still doesn't work. I am reviewing my text book and examples to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

processEntry function uses undefined variables.

This should work better :

```
var processEntry = function() {
  var cents = parseInt($("cents").value);
  var quarters = Math.floor(cents / 25); 
  var dimes = Math.floor(((cents - (quarters * 25)) / 10)); 
  var nickels = Math.floor(((cents - (quarters * 25)) - (dimes * 10)) / 5); 
  var pennies = Math.floor(((cents - (quarters * 25)) - (dimes * 10))- (nickels * 5));
  // Your OR statements need to be AND statements
  if (!isNaN(cents) && cents < 100 && cents > 0) {
    $("quarters").value = quarters;
    $("dimes").value = dimes;
    $("nickels").value = nickels;
    $("pennies").value = pennies;
  } else {
    alert("Please enter a number between 0-99")
};
```

I think that what you expect is Math.floor and not parseInt

Comment: Update I got the button working by adding an onclick on the HTML calling a function from the JS. Still working through getting the values to return